# Ubuntu corrupt PATH

Tags: bash

So I modified `profile` file under /etc/ and now I cannot use commands like `sudo`, `ls`, etc., but I cannot modify this file without `sudo`.
The question is: how can i get to `sudo` and `gedit`. I imagine it like this:

```
./pathtosudo ./pathtosu
./pathtogedit /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the absolute `sudo` path: `/usr/bin/sudo` to invoke `sudo`.

Similarly, use the absolute `gedit` path, so the complete command to edit `/etc/profile` is:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/gedit /etc/profile
```